# Emgu file size remains 0kb

Tags: opencv, video, video-capture, emgucv

i am new and got a job to build software to create a program to record videos from usb cameras and save it to the hard drive. I managed to get the dialog to work if i replace the fourcc method with -1 and use file extension to .avi. The file is being created but the recording is not present and the file size remains 0kb. dont know what to do. my code:

private Emgu.CV.Capture capture;
        private bool captureInProgress;

```
    public CameraCapture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Process Frame() below is our user defined function in which we will create an EmguCv 
    //type image called ImageFrame. capture a frame from camera and allocate it to our 
    //ImageFrame. then show this image in ourEmguCV imageBox
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    VideoWriter writer;
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
        CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;

        writer = new VideoWriter(@"C:\Video.mpeg", CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('L','M','P','2'), (int)Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, (int)Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, (int)Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, true);

    }

    //btnStart_Click() function is the one that handles our "Start!" button' click 
    //event. it creates a new capture object if its not created already. e.g at first time
    //starting. once the capture is created, it checks if the capture is still in progress,
    //if so the
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureInProgress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnStart.Text = "Start!"; //
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;

            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
        }


    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }
```

---

I Found my problem while using a messagebox. turns out the ProcessFrame keeps on working so i made some changes. this is my new code.private Emgu.CV.Capture capture;
        private bool captureInProgress;

```
    public CameraCapture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Process Frame() below is our user defined function in which we will create an EmguCv 
    //type image called ImageFrame. capture a frame from camera and allocate it to our 
    //ImageFrame. then show this image in ourEmguCV imageBox
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    VideoWriter writer;
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
        CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
        writer.WriteFrame(ImageFrame);
    }

    //btnStart_Click() function is the one that handles our "Start!" button' click 
    //event. it creates a new capture object if its not created already. e.g at first time
    //starting. once the capture is created, it checks if the capture is still in progress,
    //if so the
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureInProgress)
            {   //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnStart.Text = "Start!"; //
                writer.Dispose();
                writer = null;
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                writer = new VideoWriter(@"C:\Video.avi", -1, (int)Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 640,480, true);
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }
            captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
        {
            writer.Dispose();
            writer = null;
            capture.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try another FOURCC code. if the codec is not present, it will create a new file, but won't write anything, exactly what you get now.

Comment: I Found my problem while using a messagebox. turns out the ProcessFrame keeps on working so i made some changes. this is my new code.

Comment: Please, edit your post to remove the answer and write a real answer and then accept it.